# Modify Indicator color in SlidingTabStrip

Tags: java, android

I am an Android newbie and I'm trying to modify the underline color in my sliding tabs. When I open SlidingTabStrip I get

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;
```

My version of Photoshop doesn't recognize this color code and neither do the online color converters I checked. What color scheme is this and is there any way to convert my RGB/CMYK to this color scheme?

Comment: See this link: http://encycolorpedia.com/33b5e5 it will tell you about "0xFF33B5E5" color code.

Comment: @AnandSingh: Thanks. Is there a way to convert my RGB colors into this system?

Comment: You can use Color.parseColor(#colorcode);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simple:

To convert any color to that format just add prefix"0xFF" to color code.

For ex:

```
public static final int BLACK       = 0xFF000000;
public static final int DKGRAY      = 0xFF444444;
public static final int GRAY        = 0xFF888888;
public static final int LTGRAY      = 0xFFCCCCCC;
public static final int WHITE       = 0xFFFFFFFF;
public static final int RED         = 0xFFFF0000;
public static final int GREEN       = 0xFF00FF00;
public static final int BLUE        = 0xFF0000FF;
public static final int YELLOW      = 0xFFFFFF00;
public static final int CYAN        = 0xFF00FFFF;
```

So your color "#33b5e5" becomes "0xFF33B5E5"

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html link for more refrence.